# /dev/ttyUSB1 cannot be changed in SLIP using Contiki OS with MICAz platform

Tags: contiki

I have a problem when using the SLIP in Contiki. The port only can be changed to `/dev/ttyUSB1 in /contiki/tools` directory with the command  `sudo ./tunslip6 -s /dev/ttyUSB1 aaaa::1/64 -v6`

However, when I want to make a connection at `/contiki/examples/ipv6/rpl-border-router` directory, with the command `make connect-router`, it will then change back to `/dev/ttyUSB0`

May I know what is the problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The command `make` executes the recipes contained in the file `Makefile`. If you look within [that](https://github.com/adamdunkels/contiki-fork/blob/master/examples/ipv6/rpl-border-router/Makefile#L49) (in your example folder) you will find the recipe calling tunslip:

```
    connect-router-cooja:   $(CONTIKI)/tools/tunslip6
         sudo $(CONTIKI)/tools/tunslip6 -a 127.0.0.1 $(PREFIX)
```

you can change the command there and add `-s /dev/ttyUSB1`.